# What causes error with similar code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code that extracts names from resumes. Please see the code below:

```
public void name(string str1)
        {
            try
            {

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass Application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
                object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                string a = Server.MapPath("/resumes/" + fileUpload1.FileName);
                fileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/resumes/" + fileUpload1.FileName));
                object file = Server.MapPath("/resumes/" + fileUpload1.FileName);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = Application.Documents.Open(ref file, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                                                  ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                                                  ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                                                  ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj,
                                                  ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
                doc.Activate();
                string Doc_Content = doc.Content.Text;
                string str = Doc_Content;
                var words = str.Split(new char[] { ' ', ':', '\r', '\t' });

                for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
                {
                    string val1 = words[i].ToString();
                    val1 = val1.ToLower();
                   // string val2 = "";

                    //if (val1 != "resume")
                    //{
                    //    //i = i + 1;
                    //    string val3 = words[i].ToString();
                    //    string val4 = "";
                    //    int result = string.Compare(val3, val4, true);
                    //    if (result != 0)
                    //    {
                    //        if (j == 0)
                    //        {
                    //            string val5 = words[i].ToString();
                    //            j++;

                    //            if (words[i + 1].ToString() != "")
                    //            {
                    //                TextBox1.Text = words[i].ToString() + " " + words[i + 1].ToString();
                    //                //txtLastName.Text = words[i + 1].ToString();
                    //                doc.Close(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
                    //                return;
                    //            }
                    //            else
                    //            {
                    //                //txtLastName.Text = words[i + 2].ToString();
                    //                doc.Close(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
                    //                return;
                    //            }
                    //        }
                    //    }
                    //}


//start here


                    if (words[i].ToString().ToLower() == "resume")
                    {
                        string val3 = words[i + 1].ToString();
                        string val4 = words[i + 2].ToString();
                        TextBox1.Text = val3 + " " + val4; doc.Close(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (words[i].ToString().ToLower() == "curriculum")
                    {
                        if (words[i + 1].ToString().ToLower() == "vitae")
                        {
                            string val3 = words[i + 2].ToString();
                            string val4 = words[i + 3].ToString();
                            TextBox1.Text = val3 + " " + val4; doc.Close(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string val3 = words[i].ToString();
                        string val4 = words[i + 1].ToString();
                        TextBox1.Text = val3 + " " + val4; doc.Close(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
                        return;
                    }     
                }
 //end here
                doc.Close(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
```

The problem with above code is that it generates some error messages like the one below:-

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Roshan\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2012\Projects\HRMS\HRMS\resumes\Roshan.doc' because it is being
>   used by another process.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access
>   the file 'C:\Users\Roshan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\HRMS\HRMS\resumes\Roshan.doc' because it is being used
>   by another process.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 73:                 { Line 74:                     string path =
>   Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) + "/resumes/" +
>   fileUpload1.FileName; Line 75:
>   fileUpload1.SaveAs(path); Line 76:  Line 77:
>   fileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/resumes/" + filename));

If I uncomment the currently commented lines, and comment the code between "start here" and "end here", the code works fine. Why is it like that?

Comment: Do you have the .doc file opened in Word? Does the same thing happen if you keep it closed?

Comment: The file is not open. It work fines if I uncomment the presently commented line, and instead comment off the code between "start here" and "end here"

Comment: Use TaskManager to terminate all running Word instances before you start this. When you debug and stop this program half-way, your files remain open.

Comment: Will do the task manager.

Comment: @HenkHolterman You were right. There was literally hundreds of winword.exe instances. When I closed it all manually, I could make it work. How do I close it automatially in code ?

Comment: As stated, manage your resources (doc) with try/finally or using statements. But do note that running Office apps on a server is not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple path allowing your code to be run once without reaching the doc.close statement. Therefore a second call could trigger the exception you get.

Could you try to put the doc.close statement inside a finally block (which is the good practise anyway) ?

Comment: Will do tha, and post udates

Comment: Adding it to the finally block says that, "doc" doesn't exist in the current context...Or in other words, "doc" was first used inside the try block

Comment: Declare the doc variable outside of the try block setting it to null and assign it a value inside the try statement